# Scrape combobox

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

## GOAL

Every combination from here: https://www.repuestoscoches24.es/

## WHAT DO I ASK

Any tips on how to proceed.

## SPECIFIC PROBLEM

Combobox with 4 dropdowns, i can get a list of 1st options, can't pass value to get 2nd options.

## WHAT DID I TRY

```
# %%
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


# %% DRIVER
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"E:\msedgedriver.exe")


# %% URL
driver.get(r'https://www.repuestoscoches24.es/')


# %% TO FILL
cars = pd.DataFrame(columns=["MAKE", "YEAR", "MODEL", "MOTOR"])


# %% MAKE LIST
makesearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//select')
dropdownmake = Select(makesearch)
makeoption = dropdownmarca.options
makes = []
for make in makeoption:
    listamarcas.append(make.text)
makeoption = None


# %% NOT LOOPING THROUGH MAKES FOR DEBUGGING
# THIS CODE SHOULD BRING ALL YEAR OPTIONS BY MAKE
dropdownmake.select_by_visible_text("ABARTH")  # DEBUG
yearsearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "js-year", " " ))] | //select')
dropdownyear = Select(yearsearch)
yearoption = dropdownmarca.options
for year in yearoption:
    print(year.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP POST to https://www.repuestoscoches24.es/ajax/selector/car_selector.json return the data you are looking for.
`HTTP POST https://www.repuestoscoches24.es/ajax/selector/car_selector.json`
See `https://pastebin.com/2Zdt2NT1` for the result.
Use the browser dev tools to see which headers you need to pass to the HTTP call in order to get the data.

Comment: Did you check the json? Do you find there the info you were looking for? There is no code... I got everything from Chrome dev tools . F12 - Network - XHR

Comment: thank you I was asking just in case. I am seeing this problem tomorrow.